# MIPS - How to allocate memory for an array of integers that come from string?

Tags: arrays, string, mips, mars-simulator

Suppose there is a string:`array: .asciiz "4 5 64 12 78"`

Then how to allocate memory for an array that has to be created out of this string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `.space` directive, e.g.

```
        .data
array:  .asciiz "4 5 64 12 78"
array2: .space 40       # allocate 40 bytes
```

Comment: What if this string comes from a file and we do not know the array's size?

Comment: You should probably have specified that requirement in your question. But one solution is just to make the size of the array large enough to handle the maximum expected array size.